# IntentService Error: No default Constructor

Tags: android

I am a newbie to Android, and I am trying to use the IntentService but I get an error that it has no default constructor.
I tried restarting the Android Studio it doesn't work.

```java
package com.example.hitesh.kuchbhi;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;

import java.util.TreeSet;

public class DisplayNotification extends IntentService {
    public DisplayNotification(String name) {
        super("DisplayNotification");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // my code which even after deleting gives the same error
    }
```

log cat error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.hitesh.kuchbhi, PID: 28899
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.example.hitesh.kuchbhi.DisplayNotification: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.example.hitesh.kuchbhi.DisplayNotification has no zero argument constructor
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2728)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5233)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

AndroidManifest file Screenshot
[image]

Comment: `<!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->` | Not recommended but if you want to suspend the warning

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Just add a default constructor

```
public DisplayNotification() {
    super("DisplayNotification");
}
```

That means a constructor with no parameter

Comment: thank you so much. i almost spent an entire day for this !

Comment: You are most welcome. If this solves your problem then mark this as the answer so that others with similar problem can get the solution.

Comment: Also note that this constructor MUST be "public"

Answer (score 4):

See android developer guide for creating background services https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

From what I gather all you need to do is to create the intent service by creating a class that extends IntentService and within it, define a method that overrides onHandleIntent().

You need to remove the constructor you have defined for your DisplayNotification class or add a default constructor like so:

```
public DisplayNotification() {
    super("DisplayNotification");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you need a no parameter constructor, like so:

```
public DisplayNotification() { 
    super("DisplayNotification");
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Intent Service require one param counstructor so we need to provide the no argument constructor with parms super in it

Example

No Param constructor with param super

```
public DisplayNotification() {
    super("DisplayNotification");
}
```

Param constructor with parma super

```
public DisplayNotification(String name) {
    super(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another constructor:

```
public DisplayNotification() {
    this("DisplayNotification");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@jht

1. Another way--> The default constructor is provided by the parameterized argument
   `**public IntentService (String name)**`  where String name is used to name the worker thread so,

   ```
     public DisplayNotification(String name) {
     this(name);
   }
   ```